# UL Navigation Links not Working as Expected - HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap template that I am working with, however Once I was ready to start linking pages I noticed that the links to the other pages in the UL were not working as I expected. I searched through the site, tried a few of the fixes and posts however with no luck. Also if anyone can see it I have a second issue that is not as pressing at this time but the mobilized version of the menu expands but does not retract when you click on the hamburger icon. Any insight is much appreciated. Thank You in advance!

```css
.navigation {
 min-height: 70px;
    }

    .navigation .navbar {
 border: none;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 min-height: 70px;
    }
    .navigation .navbar .navbar-brand {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 700;
 height: 70px;
 line-height: 35px;
    }
    .navigation .navbar-default {
 background-color: #0091D5;
 box-shadow: 0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 clear: both;
    }
    .navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 500;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
    .navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
    .navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
    .navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  background: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
     }
     .navigation .btn-default:hover,
     .navigation .btn-default:focus,
     .navigation .btn-default:active,
     .navigation .btn-default.active {
   border-color: transparent;
     }
```

```html
 <section id="menu">
      <div class="navigation">
        <div id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
          
            </div> <!-- end .navbar-header -->

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul id="ulnav" class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.html" target="_parent">&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="water-damage.html" target="_parent">Water Damage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fire Damage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drying Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Restoration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Insurance & Financing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="cwaf-bg"><a href="#">Free Estimate</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- end .navbar-collapse -->

          </div> <!-- end .container -->
        </div> <!-- end #main-nav -->
      </div> <!-- end .navigation -->
    </section>
```

Comment: *"I noticed that the links to the other pages in the UL were not working as I expected"* what's the problem exactly? What's happening currently and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Basic navigation once adding a a href link it doesn't change the page. I have my home page targeted to the index and the second page to water-damage.html and the nav bar just isn't working.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine for me, the links and your menu toggle https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OjpNKe

Comment: Did you download a template or start creating your own? Possibly you downloaded a one page template with some JS that mucks with the links when the dom is generated.,

Comment: It was a one page template

Comment: @Travis Acton that was it I found the JS file messing with it. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you include boostrap?

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head<
```

Comment: Yes both are added.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved in the comments sections. This instance was related to a pre-packaged one page template which had navigation modifications in it's default JS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

please do these steps.

First you have to load bootstrap.added these links to head section.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Then You can add these code part in body section.

```
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>




<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html" target="_parent">&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="water-damage.html" target="_parent">Water Damage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fire Damage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drying Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Restoration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Insurance & Financing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="cwaf-bg"><a href="#">Free Estimate</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



</body>
```

i check this cord.it's works without any issue.i attached snapshot also.please check it.
[image: You can get nav bar like this]

[image: this works in mobile friendly also.you can check it.]